# How to get results of partial match in either SQL/Pandas/Python and fill column with conditional value?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql, dataframe

I am looking to find values that have a partial match in one column and replace the 'subcategory' column with a value derived from the 'item name' column. The 'subcategory' column is currently a duplicate of the 'item name' column.

For example, in the image below, I would like to replace the current values in the 'subcategory' column with the category of beer (IPA, Ale, Pale Ale, Lager, Pilsner, etc...) derived from a partial match on the string in 'item name' .

[SQL Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssyB4.jpg)

I have created a new column in both my Pandas dataframe and SQL database that I could manipulate to get this information, but lack the knowledge to do so.

The query I used in SQL is as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE public.all_beers_specs
ADD "Sub_Category" text;

UPDATE public.all_beers_specs
SET "Sub_Category" = all_beers_specs."Item Name";

SELECT "Sub_Category" from public.all_beers_specs
WHERE "Item Name" like '%IPA%';
```

OUTPUT:

```
Sub_Category
11 Below Hipster Sauce IPA 
21st Amendment Brew Free Or Die IPA 
21st Amendment Orange Brew Free IPA 
4th Tap Double Dry Hopped Double Dragon IPA 
4th Tap Kung Fu Robot IPA
```

Instead of having the full beer name in the column, I would like to trim it and only have IPA. I would want to repeat this process across many different beer types to get a similar result.

EDIT #1:

Here is the solution I came up with in python:

CODE:

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv(path_to_my_dataframe.csv')
#print(dataframe)


list_of_beers = dataframe['Item Name'].to_list() 


lower_case_list = [x.upper() for x in list_of_beers]

#creating a list to append results
subcategory_list =[]
for b in lower_case_list:
    #print(b)
    if 'IPA' in b:
        ipa = 'IPA'
        subcategory_list.append(ipa)
    else:
        if 'ALE' in b:
            ale = 'ALE'
            subcategory_list.append(ale)
        else:
            if 'STOUT' in b:
                stout = 'STOUT'
                subcategory_list.append(stout)
```

OUTPUT:

```
 Token                                  Item Name  ...   Price Sub_Category
0       NaN                    11 Below 7 Iron Blonde   ...   $8.82          N/A
1       NaN             11 Below Big Mistake Ba Stout   ...   $8.41        STOUT
2       NaN                11 Below Hipster Sauce IPA   ...   $9.78          IPA
3       NaN          11 Below Java Space Coffee Stout   ...  $12.48        STOUT
4       NaN               11 Below Lame Duck Pale Ale   ...   $8.76          ALE
...     ...                                        ...  ...     ...          ...
2899    NaN          Zilker Brewing Coffee Milk Stout   ...   $8.94        STOUT
2900    NaN  Zilker Brewing Friends With Benefits IPA   ...  $12.78          IPA
2901    NaN                  Zilker Brewing Marco IPA   ...   $8.94          IPA
2902    NaN     Zilker Brewing Parks and Rec Pale Ale   ...   $8.94          ALE
2903    NaN                  Zilker Heavenly Daze IPA   ...  $10.92          IPA
```

I am sure there is a more efficient way to classify the beers instead of endless if else statements, perhaps using a class or defining a function?

Also, for records 4 and 2902 I would like them to be classified as PALE ALE versus just ALE. I tried adding

```
if 'ALE' != 'PALE ALE' in B:
   ALE = ALE
```

Is there a way to match/filter exactly on those characters of those strings?

Answer (score 0):

Consider pure SQL conditional `CASE` statement in `UPDATE`. Either run below single statement in Postgres or call it via Python. Leave `pandas` for data analytics!

```sql
UPDATE public.all_beers_specs
SET "Sub_Category" = CASE 
                          WHEN all_beers_specs."Item Name" LIKE '%IPA%'      THEN 'IPA'
                          WHEN all_beers_specs."Item Name" LIKE '%Pale Ale%' THEN 'Pale Ale'
                          WHEN all_beers_specs."Item Name" LIKE '%Ale%'      THEN 'Ale'
                          WHEN all_beers_specs."Item Name" LIKE '%Lager%'    THEN 'Lager'
                          WHEN all_beers_specs."Item Name" LIKE '%Pilsner%'  THEN 'Pilsner'
                          WHEN all_beers_specs."Item Name" LIKE '%Stout%'    THEN 'Stout'
                          WHEN all_beers_specs."Item Name" LIKE '%Porter%'   THEN 'Porter'
                          ELSE NULL
                     END
```